# How to draw elliptic curve using trigonometry functions?

Tags: java, trigonometry

How can I draw an elliptic arc with Java without using any standard graphic libraries functions, like `Ellipse()` or `Path()`? 
The closest idea of what I need to do is [Elliptical Arc using Trigonometric Method](http://www.syntax-example.com/Code/draw-elliptical-arc-trigonometric-670.aspx), but it only shows random arcs, and that is not the way things should go.

The way I'm thinking of is: specify ellipse by two points, then specify angle, which will be cut from this ellipse (or vice versa). 
For drawing ellipse I used Bresenham's algorithm, but it can't be used for arcs because of mirroring. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look from parametric equations. For example, to draw a circle you should first know the circle formula:

> x^2 + y^2 = R^2

where R is the radios of the circle.

Now you should write this formula based on the angle (from 1 to 360). Based in a rectangle triangle inside the circle, its trigonometric formula will be:

cos(t)^2 + sin(t)^2 = R^2

where t is the angle, cos(t) will be X and sin(t) will be Y.

So, to draw a circle, you need to pass just the radio of your circle:

```
public static void drawCircle(int radio, double xCenter, double yCenter) {
    double t = 0;
    double xPoint;
    double yPoint;
    double xActual = xCenter;
    double yActual = yCenter + radio*sin(0);
    t += 0.01;
    while(t < 360) {
        xPoint = xCenter + radio*cos(t);
        yPoint = yCenter + radio*sin(t);
        //you should write this function based on
        //the platform you're working (Swing, AWT...)
        drawLine(xActual, yActual, xPoint, yPoint);
        t += 0.01;
        xActual = xPoint;
        yActual = yPoint;
    }
}
```

You should review the parametric formulas of the figures you need to draw:

[Ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the parametric equation for your elipse in terms of the angle.
2. Go from starting angle to second angle(plotting each x,y pair).
3. ???
4. Profit.

Parametric equation for an elipse is:

x = cos(Angle) * width/2 + xCenter

y = sin(Angle) * height/2 + yCenter

Comment: Thank you. It works, especially in combination with the other comment (: